# How to require 'ace-builds/ace' with Webpack and noParse option

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, webpack

I'm currently trying to require ace-builds (installed from bower) with webpack. Since it's a huge lib, I'm adding the whole folder to noParse option. I'm running webpack with -d option on terminal.

The problem is: when my code tries to require it, it is an empty object. Also, it's not loaded by the browser. Here are some information of what I'm doing:

My file:

```
// custom_editor.js
// ace-builds are aliased by ace keyword
var Ace = require('ace/ace');  // This is an empty Object when I'm debugging with breakpoints
```

[image: Object {}]

Config file:

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    form: path.join(__dirname, 'static/main_files/form.js'),
    vendor: [
      'jquery',
      'react',
      'underscore',
      'query-string',
      'react-dnd',
      'react-select-box'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static/bundle'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM'
    }],
    noParse: [
      /ace-builds.*/
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: [
      __dirname,
      path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ],
    alias: {
      jQueryMask: 'node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask',
      twbsDropdown: 'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown',
      'twbs-datetimepicker': 'node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker',
      ace: 'bower_components/ace-builds/src',
      'select-box': 'node_modules/react-select-box/lib/select-box',
      queryString: 'node_modules/query-string/query-string',
      moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    ),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

It was not loaded on Chrome's Network panel

[image: Network]

It is showing on Chrome's Sources panel (Don't know why because no ace.map file were loaded either)

[image: Sources]

Really running out of ideas of what I'm doing wrong here. Is there any good example that I can clone and test? (It can be another lib as well).

Comment: I've done a workaround with { externals: { 'ace/ace': 'ace } }, but I need to add a <script> tag with the path of ace, for example, <script src="/static/bower_components/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js"></script> - not optimal solution but at least works.

Comment: Having the same issue. That was the solution?

Comment: Yes. I haven't touch the code since that. Someone said to use brace, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 23):

Use `brace`. It's a browserify compatible version of the ace editor which also works with webpack. Version 0.5.1 is using ace 1.1.9.

https://github.com/thlorenz/brace

Comment: I have a size issue with this. It's add 15MB to the build in dev mode and 3MB in production mode.
I'm sure we can do better using ace as external

Comment: Brace has huge issues with custom modes and hasn't been updated in a while. Still works for barebones setups.

Comment: Ace is now at version 1.3.3 so I don't think brace is a viable option any more... :(